# How is it possible to store uploaded file on a disk with a given name?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to upload a file, and specify both the name of the file, and the disk.

With `Storage::putFileAs` I am able to specify the file name, but not the disk, and with `file('...')->store(...)` I can specify the disk, but not the file's name, only the directory.

How is it possible to set both? I was not able to find any detailed documentation about these functions, only the one about the filesystem on the [Laravel's site](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem). I am looking for a function like this:

```
fun($uploaded_file, $dir_name, $file_name, $disk_name)
```

Comment: If you would not like a file name to be automatically assigned to your stored file, you may use the storeAs method, which receives the path, the file name, and the (optional) disk as its arguments

Comment: Where am I able to find the documentation of `storeAs`, and other related methods?

Answer (score 2):

use the storage facade `disk` method.

```
Storage::disk($disk_name)->path($path)->saveFileAs($file_name);
```

Or you can use the `store` method.

Hope this helps. Good luck

Comment: There is no ref to file itself in your example. We have disk_name, path and file_name, but ... how to save here the file !?

Answer (score 1):

The storage facade has a `disk` method.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs(...);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$request->file('file')->store('folder', 's3');
```

where second argument is the disk name.